# How to format string parameters before sending to MySql in .NET?

Tags: .net, mysql, string

How can I check a string for incorrect MySQL syntax caused by (') ?

for example: We Bike'd fast

I need to get rid of the ' before inserting it into the Database.

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229889/sanitizing-mysql-user-parameters

Comment: Are you looking for a built in method that handles all MySQL special characters or just a way to look for and remove a character you specify?

Comment: Say I have a bunch of variables containing strings that will then be put into a MySQL query. I need to some how validate that there are no characters in that insert query that would cause an error. The only character that I know does this would be the ' symbol

Comment: Instead of manual string escaping, why not use Parametrized SQL that will handle this for you?

Comment: I'll have to look into parameterizing my query I guess, but i was kind of just looking for the quick and dirty way to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, you will get the benefit of stopping SQL injection, and other benefits such as performance, see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html Quick and dirty here not the best since having Parametrized SQL across the whole app will help security and performance and your coworkers will like you ;)

Comment: Side note: "We Bike'd fast" is bad grammar.  :)  Should be "We biked fast".  I'd suggest "We biked quickly", but to me that means "We quickly started biking".

Comment: @cHao I was just giving a very rough example ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is:

```
textValue = textValue.Replace("'","''");
```

But it is usually better to use command parameters.

See [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) Property on msdn. (I do not know the MySql equivalent)

EDIT:

Example with Replace:

```
string sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name ='{0}'",
                           textBox1.Value.Replace("'","''"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the .Replace way to change the string. Could I just do Value.Replace("'", "") after getting the string for my variable?

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`MysqlCommand`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand) and command paramters to build your insert statement, this will do the escaping for you.

Alternatively there is a [`EscapeString`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html) method you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the using `System.Web` directive to your .cs file and use the `HTMLEncode` which will then replace `'` with `&apos` but when you read it back out you'll have to call `HTMLDecode()` to convert it back to `'`.

This you would use before you create your parametrized statement on the front end. Then pass the end result as a parameter to your sqlCommand.